# Is it possible to wrap the original textures into the new mesh without distortion?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

I've been working on this mod for Fallout 4 where I intend to "restore" the damaged piece of clothing. The meshes are good but the textures within that region are all over the place:

[image]
I've searched everywhere but couldn't find an answer to this. Any way I can fix that without having to create an entirely new texture set?

And I've been using Blender for only 2 days with no previous experience whatsoever, so please bear with me.

Comment: Looks like messed up UV coordinates. I *can* probably be fixed without a new texture, but whether or not it is easy or doable by hand is another matter.

Comment: Did you unwrap the new faces? Could you provide a sample file to test?

Answer (score 3):

As long as your texture has image information for the ripped out part, you can correct the UVs by hand. One quick way to do it us by using the **Pin Tool** in UV Editor.

**Example**
I have a mesh with a hole in the middle (left). After filling the hole manually I may end up with a highly distorted, but still connected UV projection (right).
[image]
[image]

When selecting the original mesh part in Edit Mode, by default only the selcted and correctly unwrapped faces are shown in UV Image Editor. Move cursor to the UV Editor, select all vertices with <kbd>A</kbd> and press <kbd>P</kbd> to pin these vertices. This means they will not be changed if the mesh is unwrapped again.
[image]

Next select all vertices, including the newly created with distorted UVs, and unwrap using the default method (in Edit Mode: select all, <kbd>U</kbd> -> Unwrap; in UV Editor: select all, <kbd>U</kbd>)
[image]

The distorted parts are automatically repaired whilst the original parts are untouched. Optionally, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to remove the pins again.